During the pandemic, when many were stuck at home and looking for escapist reading, fictional romance blossomed. So whatever caused the blossom?

During the pandemic, when many were stuck at home and looking for escapist reading, fictional romance blossomed. In the year to May, romance print sales were up by 52%, according to a market-research firm. List-price sales grew by 74%. Annual growth in sales went from 6% in 2020 to more than 50% last year.

-From Romance (as a category) is far from dead
Here is a reading question:
Which of the following may contribute to the popularity of fictional romance?
A. Shifts of writing styles.
B. The marketing strategy.
C. The immobility during the pandemic.
D. People’s attempt to escape reading.
Obviously, the answer is either C or D. But I think it is confusing to choose Between C and D. As a whole, they both are the reason for the popularity of fictional romance. So is it a  bad or at least badly worded question?

Escapist in your quote does not mean escaping from reading. It means escaping from reality by choosing reading material that differs from reality. I watched lots of escapist romantic comedies this week to distract myself from the fact that my partner has walked out on me.

Are you sure you copied D correctly? As it is worded, it could also mean, people who try to run away from reading!

The reason for the increase in sales was not due to a specific genre but due to free time,  people had the time to actually read novels/literature. I would also bet there was an increase in binge watching movies and series too, especially Marvel's so-called "universe"–more escapist than that.

@Mari-LouA - don't multiple-choice questions often have wildly wrong choices placed to catch out the lazy or cheating student? Couldn't D be such a choice?

So if D was “people’s choice of escapist reading”, would it still be wrong? Seeking for escapist reading is the direct cause of the popularity of fictional romance, though it was the result of or amid the pandemic. In this case, can D at least be part of the reason for the increasing readers? Or it is not called “reason” but something else?

you've written/copied (D) ....to escape reading. That's why I asked if you copied it correctly. It grammatical but it doesn't mean what you think it does.

No, it can’t be D.  It is C.  People were stuck at home and hence read more, in fact, at least of the fictional romance types; these types alleviate their unpleasant feeling.
Escapist

Escapist ideas, activities, or types of entertainment make people think about pleasant or unlikely things instead of the uninteresting or unpleasant aspects of their life.


You can't say attempt to try, because both words mean the same. You could say "People's choice of escapist reading".

Some of comments suggest that there may be mistakes in the OP or the source reading exercise. I'm taking the question at face value, and as it's currently written, C is the only correct answer.
It's true that the quoted paragraph has more than one possible reason for the blossoming of fictional romance:

Many [people] were stuck at home.
Those people were looking for escapist reading.

Sentence (1) is the first reason; sentence (2) is a follow up reason. Being stuck at home leads to the search for escapist reading, which in turn leads to a blossoming in fictional romance.
However, the reading question is different. It asks, which of the listed reasons might have contributed to the blossoming of romance fiction? We are therefore asked to compare sentences A-D with the content of the preceding paragraph.
A and B are obviously wrong, because the paragraph doesn't focus on either writing styles or marketing strategy. Sentence C is a valid answer: immobility matches being stuck at home. So what about sentence D?
The key is to understand that although this sentence could have matched the second reason, as worded it doesn't actually do so. This is because escaping reading is not the same as escapist reading. To be a valid answer, sentence D would have to be something like People's attempt to find reading that distracted them from their problems.
